# matplotlib and pandas plot subplots on a new row

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I can plot my pandas dataframe column values as subplots easily in a **1XN** matrix.

However, when i want to plot it on a **MXN** matrix, i get errors.

Example:

```
df_play = pd.DataFrame({'a':['cat','dog','cat'],
                        'b':['apple','orange','orange'],
                        'c':['boy','boy','girl'],
                        'd':['chair','table','desk']
                       },dtype='category')


fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,len(df_play.columns),figsize=(14,6))
for i,x in enumerate(df_play.columns):
    df_play[x].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',ax=axs[i])
```

[image]

Doing this gives me errors( example i want to view my subplots as a 2X2 matrix):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,len(df_play.columns)/2,figsize=(14,6))
for i,x in enumerate(df_play.columns):
    df_play[x].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',ax=axs[i])

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the subplots are 2-dimensional, `subplots` returns a figure and a 2-dimensional NumPy array of axes. Therefore, use

```
axs = axs.ravel()
```

to make the 2D array of axes 1-dimensional. Then you can use `axs[i]` to index `axs` as desired:

```
for i,x in enumerate(df_play.columns):
    df_play[x].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',ax=axs[i])
```

`axs.ravel()` enumerates the axes going from left to right across the rows from the top row down to the bottom row. To enumerate the axes going from top to bottom down the columns from the left-most to the right-most column, use `axs.ravel(order='F')`.